# Find the total distance flown by a fly which alters travelling between two cyclists moving towards each other with given speeds and wind conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Statement of the problem:
Two cyclists, Mike and Josh, simultaneously started toward each other from two towns $d = 24$ km apart. Josh rode at $v_j = 25 $km/hr, and Mike at $v_m= 15$ km/h. The moment they start, a fly also starts from Josh towards Mike and after reaching Mike, immediately returns towards Josh. The fly continues back and forth motion between the cyclists till the cyclists meet. Air speed of fly is $v_f = 30$ km/h and the wind blows always towards Mike with a constant velocity, $w= 10$ km/h. Find the total distance $s$ flown by the fly.

This problem is similar to the [Bee travelling between two trains problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805312/bee-flying-between-two-trains-problem) but the added condition is that the velocity of the bee(in context of the linked question)/ the fly (this question), changes with respect to the "direction" its headed at.
I'm looking for an approach which doesn't brute force, and something elegant like switching of frames, or something subtle that I have missed.

For Example I was trying to solve the problem with respect to the wind so that the fly, travels in constant velocity, and our "distance" travelled in this relative frame would just be $v_f \cdot t$ where $t$ is the time required for both the cyclicists to collide in the relative frame.

The answer is $s=21 $ km and
the hint given is: "For the whole journey the displacement of Josh and that of the fly are the same".

I would appreciate a solution which uses the following hint.